# Find arrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Error -> listViewAdapter <- Error.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Estou querendo fazer tipo um findview mas com o arrayadapter que esta na class do meu fragment, e o find taria na mainActivity, eu quero fazer qual quer coisa para tentar achar o listViewAdapter que é o nome da minha ArrayAdapter que esta no fragment, mais não esta achando no MainActivity.

Comment: Qual a duvida? Simplesmente jogar código e esperar que alguem advinhe não é uma boa forma de obter resposta. Edite a pergunta explicando sua duvida,